# Javascript onchange event not working in my code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onchange

what is wrong with this code? Why is my onchange event not working? I have tried a lot already and it's making me nuts. Please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type=text/javascript>
function populate(s1,s2){
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
var optionArray ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette",
"impala|Impala"];
}
else if(s1.value=="Dodge"){
var optionArray=["|", "avanger|Avanger", "challenger|Challenger",
"charger|Charger"];
}
else if(s1.value=="Ford"){
var optionArray=["|", "mustang|Mustang", "shelby|Shelby"];
}
for(var option in optionArray){
var pair=optionArray[option].split("|");
var newOption=document.createElement("option");
newOption.value=pair[0]; 
newOption.innerHtml=pair[1];
s2.options.add(newOption);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id, 'slct2')">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
<option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Car Model:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone, please point out to me where is the exact problem...Let me try running it accordingly

Comment: `innerHtml` is not the same as `innerHTML`

Comment: and you should be setting the text, not html of an option. And you really should not be using a for in loop for an array.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.  The browser is telling you what those errors are.  Look at the JavaScript console.

Comment: Ever heard of the javascript debugger that exists in every broswer?

Comment: There need to be a `=` at `var optionArray ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette",
"impala|Impala"];`

Comment: @RiggsFolly *"Ever heard of the javascript debugger that exists in every broswer?"* -- Likely not, as he wouldn't be asking this question otherwise. I don't think there is any need to go all rude on beginners.

Comment: haha..no issues buddy...i'm ok...i do now know of browser debuggers...also jsfiddle...but things ain't still working even after i debug in jsfiddle and copy paste the code...thanks to Riggs and John anyways

Answer (score 0):

Two changes. Change `innerHtml` to `innerHTML` and assign an `=` sign in

```
if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
var optionArray ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette",
"impala|Impala"];
}
```

correct the above to

```
if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
var optionArray = ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette",
"impala|Impala"];
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vjfc5xyu/)

Comment: tried is...still it aint working..but thanks anyways...i'm gonna use the database method...i figured out my list is gonna be quite big

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this, 'slct2')">
```

js:

```
populate = function(s1,s2) {
    var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
    s2.innerHTML = "";
    if(s1.value == "Chevy"){
        var optionArray = ["|", "camaro|Camaro", "corvette|Corvette",
"impala|Impala"];
    }
    else if(s1.value=="Dodge"){
        var optionArray=["|", "avanger|Avanger", "challenger|Challenger",
"charger|Charger"];
    }
    else if(s1.value=="Ford"){
        var optionArray=["|", "mustang|Mustang", "shelby|Shelby"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair=optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption=document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value=pair[0]; 
        newOption.innerHTML=pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/xkyffr4h/1/

Comment: thanks...still there's something wrong i dont know..it aint working...anyways thanks 4 taking the time...gonna use the database and AJAX method...my option lists are gonna be quite big i figured